# Do c++ templates use the heap?

Tags: c++, templates, heap-memory

According to this presentation, templates don't take heap and has zero-overhead.

Is this true, where can you look this up? Generally, how to you figure out if a c++ feature you used allocated to the heap?

[presentation link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=752C1S-C6kE)

Comment: Templates are code, not data. Only data can go on the heap.

Comment: Compile-time heap, or run-time heap? I think you're getting these two things confused. C++ is renown for having long compile times because it has a lot of tools that allows more work to be done in compilation, such as using templates. Generally whether you write a class/function "manually" or use templates, the resultant executable should be the same.

Comment: @RaymondChen already gave the answer. The presentation you linked is over 2 hours long. Can you give a timestamp where this information was given?

Comment: This question is rather similar to the question "Do templates use the color purple"? The answer in both cases would be "in your IDE perhaps".

Comment: A template can call `new` or `malloc` if that is your question. The template per se doesn't "use" the heap in that sense, just like a `#define` doesn't "use" the heap.

Answer (score 5):

Templates are a compile-time feature. A built executable (or library) does not contain templates. It contains code for different template instantiations. The more types the template is instantiated with, the larger the executable might be. This does not mean that templates make your executable grow bigger, no, templates just make your source code shorter.

Obviously, the heap has nothing to do with executable size or templates.